# FileNotFoundException trying to send JSON to .NET webservice using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I am trying to parse a response from an `InputStream` from a `HttpURLConnection` using the following code.I get an error when trying to get the `InputStream`.I am just looking to get a response to check if the web-servcice call worked `OK`.

```
     static final String SOAP_ACTION="http://888topup.com/ImageProcess.svc/UploadImage"; 
    java.net.URL url=null;
    try {
        url = new java.net.URL(SOAP_ACTION);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bad URL",e);
    }
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("Vaue", value);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Create JSONObjerct throws an error");
    }
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error opening connection",e1);
    }
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    try {
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip deflate sdch");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error setting header",e);
    }
    try {
        OutputStream os=urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        byte[] data=obj.toString().getBytes();
        bos.write(data);
        InputStream is=urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String response;
        response=br.readLine();

        Log.d(TAG, "Response: "+response);
        bos.close();
        br.close();
        is.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error peforming read-write operations",e);
    }
```

Here is the `Logcat` entry for what happened when I tried to run this code:

```
  MainActivity(9628): Error peforming read-write operations
  MainActivity(9628): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://888topup.com/ImageProcess.svc/UploadImage
  MainActivity(9628):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
  MainActivity(8989):   at com.example.imageuploadtest.MainActivity.sendStringToServiceUsingRest(MainActivity.java:184)
  MainActivity(8989):   at com.example.imageuploadtest.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:149)
  MainActivity(8989):   at com.example.imageuploadtest.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:66)
```

## EDIT:

The operation as specified in [WSDL](http://888topup.com/ImageProcess.svc?wsdl):

```
<wsdl:operation name="UploadImage">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IImageProcess/UploadImage"   message="tns:IImageProcess_UploadImage_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IImageProcess/UploadImageResponse" message="tns:IImageProcess_UploadImage_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Adding `urlConnection.connect()` before writing data to the `OutputStream` does not work either.

## EDIT:Using the `URL(SOAP_ACTION)` and passing jsondata works from Sencha-Touch for someone else who tested it.

Tried passing JSONObject as String instead of byte data.Did not work either?

Comment: You've omitted the actual exception.

Comment: @EJP added the exception and the URL

Comment: Now that you've provided it, what part of `not found ... http://888topup.com/ImageProcess.svc/UploadImage` don't you understand?

Comment: I tried passing JSON data to output stream to the service,does it mean that the request was not successfull,how do I get the response from the service without using InputStream

Comment: You're missing the point. It's the URL itself that's invalid. Nothing to do with the code.

Comment: I have posted wsdl:operation Should I use this URL instead http://tempuri.org/IImageProcess/UploadImage...this redirects to bing in the browser

Comment: Come off it. How are we supposed to know what the correct URLs are for your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few mistakes with what I was doing,firstly I was passing the wrong parameter `Vaue` instead of `Value` to the service.

```
   JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    try {
        String value_key="Value";
        obj.put(value_key, value);
        Log.d(TAG,obj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Create JSONObjerct throws an error");
    }
```

Secondly,I was trying to parse a response when no response was being sent.So, I replace the code to get the `InputStream` with the following code:

```
 int response=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

The entire code is here:

```
java.net.URL url=null;
    try {
        url = new java.net.URL(SOAP_ACTION);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bad URL",e);
    }
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    try {
        String value_key="Value";
        obj.put(value_key, value);
        Log.d(TAG,obj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Create JSONObjerct throws an error");
    }
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error opening connection",e1);
    }
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    try {
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        //urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip deflate sdch");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error setting header",e);
    }
    try {
        urlConnection.connect();
        DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        dos.write(obj.toString().getBytes());
        int response=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(TAG, "Response code: "+response);
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error peforming read-write operations",e);
    }
```

And finally I used this to send the data to the web-service as binary data:

```
  DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    dos.write(obj.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: You could avoid many problems when not using `HttpURLConnection` directly, but use a tiny wrapper like [DavidWebb](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb). [Here is a Gist](https://gist.github.com/hgoebl/8313248) where you can see an example.